# Radio app into a service

Tags: java, android

Hi I was following a tutorial I found to make an app that plays a radio, the app works until you exit because then the sound stops. I have researched and found out that it needs to be a service but I am not sure how to change it to a service, this is the code I used.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    public class myMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();
    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("stream url");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
}
```

I tried changing it but I am not sure how to put the functions from the main activity into a new service and then run it.

```
public class MyService extends Service implements     MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.action.PLAY";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        mMediaPlayer =  private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource("stream url");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
} // initialize it here
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block main        thread
    }
}

/** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
    player.start();
}
```

}

I tried using the above code but I do not know how to start the action and whether or not it will work.
    Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a service from your main activity.

```
startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY));
```

your service class.

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    public static MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();     
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ACTION_PLAY))
        processPlayRequest();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Hi how would I implement all the functions from the main activity to this and then be able to call them from main activity?

Comment: Hi I put the classes in but get a error saying can't find variable and unknown member ACTION_PLAY